# Do we know if the Dutch vulgar/slang term "stront" is related to the Italian vulgar/slang term "stronzo"?

Tags: etymology, italian, dutch, profanity

I have for years known that there was a **Dutch** bad word "**stront**" meaning "shit" but I expected it was spelled "stroent" until I looked it up just now.

I have also known the **Italian** bad word "**stronzo**" which has many uses but literally also means "shit".

Only in the last half hour or so did I consider the similarity and wonder if they could be related. I haven't been able to find any discussion of this or an etymology for the Dutch word, but apparently the Italian word comes from Lombard.

Do we know if and how these words from a pair of countries without a border might be related?

Comment: I, too, have always wondered about this. Could you elaborate on the Lombard word? What does it look like? What did you find? I'll look up the Dutch etymology if available in the Woordenboek der Nederlandsche Taal (available for free online, the world's largest dictionary).

Comment: Yes I tried to look up the Dutch too, took me a while to locate the dictionary, then Google Translate didn't work very well with it. As for *stronzo*/Lombard that was in Wiktionary: From Lombardic strunz (“dung”). **Aha!!** Italian Wiktionary is more helpful: dal (germanico) longobardo strunz, sterco

Comment: Apparently *stront* comes from a Proto-Germanic root **strentan-/*stranta(n)-/*strant(i)ō(n)-*, which meant something like "something long and stiff", after what the WNT calls "the shape of solid excrement". It also notes that Latin borrowed it as *strundius* in the 9th century (which is just after the Lombards were defeated by Charlemagne). So the Italians and Latin in general borrowed it from the German! http://gtb.inl.nl/iWNTLINKS/DATADIR/paginazy.html?EWN+/iWDB/search?actie=article_content&wdb=EWN&id=ewn011251

Comment: I was ignorant of who the Lombards were - I thought the word referred to a province of Italy or somesuch `\-:`. Write up an answer and I will accept it - good work!

Comment: Hey, we both did the same work, mostly! The Lombards were a Germanic tribe that invaded Italy in the 6th century and settled there, giving modern Lombardy its name.

Comment: Lombardic explanation makes lots of sense, since it shows t-z mutation.
Consider also that in some Lombardic dialects, "schitú" (pron. skit'u) (the "ú" usually indicates large size) means something like "having a lot of sh*t to do", it could have the very same origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently stront comes from a Proto-Germanic root **strentan-*/**stranta(n)-*/**strant(i)ō(n)-,* which meant "something long and stiff", after what the *[Etymologisch Woordenboek van het Nederlands](http://gtb.inl.nl/iWNTLINKS/DATADIR/paginazy.html?EWN%20/iWDB/search?actie=article_content&wdb=EWN&id=ewn011251)* calls "the shape of solid excrement".

The EWN also notes that Latin borrowed it as strundius, which is attested in the 9th century. As you say in your comment based on Italian Wiktionary, Italian got *stronzo* from Lombardic *strunz*. The Lombards were a Germanic tribe that invaded Italy in the 6th century and settled there, giving modern Lombardy its name; so it makes sense that they should use the Germanic word (Middle German *strunze* meant "stront").

But Wiktionary also mentions Italian/Lombard *sterco*, which must come from Latin *stercus* "dung", related to Greek *skôr,* stem *skat-* "dung", as in scatological. So perhaps the Italian word is a fusion of the Germanic word and the Latin word?

The EWN says *stront* is related to *stronk* "tree trunk" and Proto-Indo-European **stred-* / **stredh-*, which in turn may be an extension of **(s)ter(h1)-* "be or become stiff". Which happens to resemble Latin *stercus*.

Comment: I wonder if there is as good an online Italian dictionary as we have for Dutch?

Comment: @hippietrail: Hmm I don't think so. I once downloaded a digital version of the largest Italian dictionary, but it was not normally available online, alas.

Comment: I would assume (though I haven't checked) that this is the same as Swedish _strunt_ (n.), _strunta_ (v.), which means ‘shit’ in the metaphorical ‘I don't give a shit’ way (_ge strunt i_ = ‘give _strunt_ in(to)’ = not give a toss; _strunta i_ = not give a toss. Compare also _skita i_, which is literally ‘shit in’, but means the same thing).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Ah, but this *strunt* is only used in those metaphorical expressions?

Comment: Well, I’ve only ever **heard** it in the metaphorical sense … but I have a feeling it is derived from a literal sense. And the [Dictionary of the Swedish Academy](http://g3.spraakdata.gu.se/saob/show.phtml?filenr=2/30/156.html) seems to agree: the first definition, marked as †obsolete, is ‘excrement’, and the etymological note connects it to Dutch _stront_ and also notes that the Latin _strundius, struntus_ are likely loans from Germanic.

Comment: For what is worth, here's is the [entry](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stronzo/) at the *Vocabolario Treccani*. It says that *stronzo* means "solid fecal mass of cylindical shape" (which conforms to my experience of the practical usage) and that it derives from a reconstructed Longobard's *strunz*.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Good. It doesn't say anything about the origin of the Lombard word?

Comment: @Cerberus Unfortunately not, and I cannot find any other reference

Comment: @DenisNardin: OK. But a relation seems likely.